# I am using php and ajax for making a suggestion list. not getting the distinct values even if i use keyword distinct in query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, distinct, suggestbox

I was getting distinct values before I gave the `%` symbol in regular expression for searching.

Here is my code.entries.

```
$arr = [];
if(isset($_GET['pat']))
    $x = $_GET['pat'].'%';
else
    $x = '%';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT distinct university FROM colleges WHERE university LIKE '%".$x."%';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    array_push($arr,$row['university']);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

How will I get distinct values? I don't want duplicates.

Comment: Cool. Did you have a question?

Comment: How will i get the distinct values?i don't want duplicate entries.

Comment: Have you checked if your database field university "different values" is about empty spaces? try `distinct trim(university)`

Comment: If query not return than use in Php $arr[$row['university']] = $row['university'];

Comment: Note you are generating doubled `%` in the end of `LIKE` argument